# Android: How to turn off IME for an EditText?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

How do I turn off the IME-functionality of an `EditText`?

Or: How do I avoid the display of the IME-keyboard?

I have a layout where my special keyboard sits below the `EditText` so there's no need to show the IME. Please understand that I cannot implement my keyboard as IME as it is specific for this very `EditText` and using it in any other context would only cause problems.

I tried to use

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in the `onCreate()` of the activity, but that doesn't seem to do anything in this situation.

Comment: Is this custom EditText allowed to take input from the hardware keyboard? If not, ie if it's only controlled from your custom software keyboard, then maybe it shouldn't be editable at all...

Comment: @reuben: Well, that's the problem. The user shouldn't be limited to the soft-keyboard. He/she should also be allowed to navigate around by tapping into the `EditText` as the length of text isn't limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think I found a way to do it... subclass `EditText` and override [`onCheckIsTextEditor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onCheckIsTextEditor()) to return false:

```
public class EditTextEx extends EditText {

    public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

I've tested it and I can't get the soft keyboard to show at all.

Comment: Yes, awesome! You are the first to answer any of my four questions yet. Congratulations :)

Comment: `editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);` has the same effect

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: This does disable the cursor, though.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to get it working I also tried:

```
inputField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    });

inputField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Both get called, but neither hide the IME-pop-up.