# Disable input method of EditText but keep cursor blinking

Tags: android, android-widget

In my Android application, I want an `EditText` with `android:editable="false"` but the cursor blinking. The cursor blinking seems doesn't work after "editable" is set to false.

I just want to use my own Keyboard widget(not the system's soft keyboard), and keep the cursor blinking.

Is there any idea to make that possible?

Comment: I had originally posted an answer, using `android:inputType="none"`. However, now that I think of this, I don't think it's possible. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense for the developers to make such a thing possible. I would suggest you make a custom `TextView` class with your own touch listener.

Comment: you have any problem to solve this issue by setting `TextWatcher` for EditText ??

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I look up the source code of TextView.shouldBlink() & TextView.onDraw(4.0.3), and the condition of cursor blinking is "mMovement != null && (isFocused() || isPressed())" and isCursorVisible(), does it really need to make a custom TextView? or we may have an easy way?

Comment: I'm really not sure of any easy way. From Google's perspective, it doesn't make any sense to have a cursor blink if the user cannot interact via some keyboard. The only time I've seen a custom keyboard like this was in the game Spirit, and that uses a custom `EditText` of some kind.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try leaving out the xml attribute `android:editable` entirely and then try the following in combination to

keep the cursor blinking **and** prevent touch events from popping up a native IME(keyboard)..

```
/*customized edittext class 
* for being typed in by private-to-your-app custom keyboard.
* borrowed from poster at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131448/android-how-to-turn-off-ime-for-an-edittext
*/
public class EditTextEx extends EditText {
    public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {

        return false; //for some reason False leads to cursor never blinking or being visible even if setCursorVisible(true) was called in code.
    }       
}
```

Step 2
change the above method to say  `return true;`

Step 3
Add another method to above class.

```
@Override
public boolean isTextSelectable(){
    return true;
}
```

Step 4
In the other location where the instance of this class has been instantiated and called `viewB` I added a new touch event handler

```
    viewB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            viewB.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Step 5  Check to make sure XML and or EditText instantiation code declares IME/keyboard type to be 'none'.  I didnt confirm relevance, but Im also using the focusable attributes below.

```
<questionably.maybe.too.longofa.packagename.EditTextEx
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="none">
```

Sorry for so many xml attributes. My code uses them all, testing in `4.2.1`, and has results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I'm on Nexus 4 and OS is 6.0.1. In my case, `Step 5` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the xml attribute

> android:cursorVisible="false"

or the java function

> setCursorVisible(false).

it will work

Comment: He wants the cursor to BE visible. Additionally, I don't think this code works if it is not focusable.

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding this method for anyone looking for and answer. I have tried many methods but only this one worked from me.

```
 public static void disableSoftKeyboard(final EditText v) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        v.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        v.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I called the following from onCreate(), but this affects all EditTexts.

```
private void hideKeyboard ()
{
    getWindow ().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
}
```