# Making a calculator app w/ buttons and TextView with blinking cursor and NO keyboard focusability. Is it possible without using Canvas to draw cursor?

Tags: android, textview, calculator, drawable

There is the proper method which is to draw the line myself via canvas. I want to avoid the complexity and I am asking here to double check if there is a simpler method I can use.

I am currently using a temporary method, which is to use SpannableString to highlight the nearest text 'character' that the cursor is on. But as you know, this "selects" the current character. I prefer the cursor to be between two characters instead of on top of one character.

I also don't want keyboard focus because I already laid out some nice buttons for the user to interact with. I don't want the app to use the Android keyboard and input methods. Only my buttons should be enough.

I tried accessing TextView methods:

1. Remove keyboard focus and input via the manifest
2. setFocusable(false)
3. setFocusableInTouchMode(false)
4. setCursorVisible(true) or cursorVisible="true"

This didn't work for me. I know that if I make the TextView focusable, then the cursor will be visible. But if it's not focusable, then the cursor does not show, even if it it is: cursorVisible="true".

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
[Disable input method of EditText but keep cursor blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870577/disable-input-method-of-edittext-but-keep-cursor-blinking)

> Maybe try leaving out the xml attribute `android:editable` entirely
>   and then try the following in combination to
>
> keep the cursor blinking **and** prevent touch events from popping up
>   a native IME(keyboard)..
>
> ```
> /*customized edittext class 
> * for being typed in by private-to-your-app custom keyboard.
> * borrowed from poster at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131448/android-how-to-turn-off-ime-for-an-edittext
> */
> public class EditTextEx extends EditText {
>     public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>         super(context, attrs);
>     }
>     @Override 
>     public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
>
>         return false; //for some reason False leads to cursor never blinking or being visible even if setCursorVisible(true) was
> ```
>
> called in code.
>           }
>       }
>
> Step 2 change the above method to say  `return true;`
>
> Step 3 Add another method to above class.
>
> @Override   public boolean isTextSelectable(){      return true;    }
>
> Step 4 In the other location where the instance of this class has been
>   instantiated and called `viewB` I added a new touch event handler
>
> ```
>   viewB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
>       @Override
>       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
>           viewB.setCursorVisible(true);
>           return false;
>       }       });
> ```
>
> Step 5  Check to make sure XML and or EditText instantiation code
>   declares IME/keyboard type to be 'none'.  I didnt confirm relevance,
>   but Im also using the focusable attributes below.
>
> ```
> <questionably.maybe.too.longofa.packagename.EditTextEx
>     android:id="@+id/editText1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:focusable="true"
>     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>     android:inputType="none">
> ```
>
> Sorry for so many xml attributes. My code uses them all, testing in
>   `4.2.1`, and has results.   Hope this helps.